# C Preprocessor Macros priority of define

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to print last defined macros in my code:

```
#define VAR   1234

#undef  VAR
#define VAR   1111
int main(){

printf("%d",VAR);
while(1);
}
```

The output is `1111`

**If I want to define in another library.**

But when I redefine `VAR` in an external library output is the first defined value. This is it:

iIn main code:

```
#include "variable.h"

int main(){
   REDEFINE();
   printf("%d",VAR);
   while(1);
}
```

variable.h

```
#define VAR 1234
void REDEFINE(void);
```

variable.c

```
void REDEFINE(){
    #undef VAR
    #define VAR 1111
}
```

In this case, output is `1234` and the `REDEFINE()` function didn't change the `VAR` value. How can I change my macro variables in `variable.c` without having to redefine in top of my main code?

Comment: Preprocessor directives do not run at runtime, they run before the compilation. You cannot do things like this.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Preprocessor only sees included files. What is in a different .c file is completely invisible for Prepro.

Comment: Macro definitions are not executable code.  They apply (only) at compile time, in the portion of the translation unit from their definition to any un- or redefinition.

Comment: After preprocessor runs, the compiler has such code to compile: `void REDEFINE() {}`.

Comment: If you want a solution tell us what you want to achieve. Using ("printing") the last defined value is what you already get; just only within the "visible universe".

Comment: Macros are not functions, functions are not macros.

Comment: @MohammadFarahi, there is no "solution" to the problem as you have posed it.  It's unclear what the real problem is that you were trying to solve with this approach; it may be that you can solve it by *returning* the wanted value from a function or by having the function set the value of a visible variable.

Comment: I think we might be looking at a XY problem.

Comment: Pretty sure now that it is X (I need to override many macros and want to do that in one file) Y (I try to change macros inside a function in a code file and that fails). Can you confirm Mohammad?

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is a one pass translation phase that does no more than preform token substitution before your code is compiled.

`define` and `undef` are not executable statements, they are done and gone long before your program is finished compiling.

If you want a modifiable value, you need to define a variable (with static storage duration) to hold it. So a different `variable.c`:

```
static int value = 1234;

int set_value(int new) {
  int prev = value;
  value = new;
  return prev;
}

int get_value() {
  return value;
}
```

Comment: because of hundred macro defines in original code, I have to redefine all in a single lib and not able to define them as a static int variable

Comment: Now that is a reason I understand and it also sheds light on what you actually need. See my answer. And please consider editing this vital information into your question. As a comment here, it might get lost, for example if Story Teller decides to delete his answer. Then anybody else trying to help you would be doomed...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how preprocessor works. By the time the compiler runs, the preprocessor's run is over. It's all done before your program's execution time - even before your program turns into something that can be executed.

`VAR` gets replaced with `1234` or `1111`, whichever one is in effect at the time the preprocessor reaches the line with `VAR` in it, so the compiler does not see `VAR` at all: instead, it sees the number that the preprocessor uses for its replacement.

The call  to `REDEFINE()` has no effect:

```
void REDEFINE(){
#undef VAR
#define VAR 1111
}
```

preprocessor directives change `VAR` to `1111` in the space of the translation unit that you are compiling, at the time the preprocessor reaches the new `#define` line.

Answer (score 0):

I provide an answer for the situation that you really have to redefine many macros and want to do that in one file. But please double check.
This is going to become a **maintenance hell**.
I have a superstition that using `undef` is evil, or at least very unlucky.

Do not try to undef-redefine in a .c file.
Do so in a new header.

REDEFINE.H:

```
#undef VAR
#define VAR 1111
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "variable.h"
#include "REDEFINE.H"

int main(){
    //REDEFINE(); // not needed
    printf("%d",VAR);
    while(1); // This is of course not in your actual code,
    // make sure that there is a return statement instead.
}
```